Pump.fun Website "Connect Wallet" crypto account creation tool
The website pump.fun https://pump.fun/board has a "connect wallet" tool upper right corner which creates an account and connects a crypto wallet.
curious if anyone can help find out which tools or applications they are using. Id like to use the same tool for my own web 3 based project.
I am creating a simple Wordpress website which offers a service, accepting only crypto as payment. Curious which plugin or application pump.fun website https://pump.fun/board is using so I too can use that application or plugin.
thanks.

Hi there! Not sure pump.fun/board  is a WordPress site, Also i see connect with wallet you need some API
if check main script is code is not wordpress and used some script for autentification
if you check browser console you can see many API requests https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-reference/endpoint/list-api-keys
